# Grid view Item does not take all width availabel UWP Xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, uwp

I wan't to display a grid view list item but I don't know why the gridview (in purple) take all the place I wan't but the grid elements does not take all the width evailable they wrap the content, what I'm missing ?

```
<GridView 
                Background="Purple"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Margin="20,20,20,0"
                ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"
                Style="{StaticResource GridViewStyle}"
                SelectionMode="Multiple"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                Background="White"
                BorderThickness="1"
                BorderBrush="Gray">

                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Creator, Mode=OneWay}"/>                            </StackPanel>

                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,20"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                </Style>
            </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                   MaximumRowsOrColumns="1"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        </GridView>
```

Here is the render :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the items to stack like this, you should be using a `ListView` instead. All you have to do is to remove the whole `<GridView.ItemsPanel>...</GridView.ItemsPanel>` code, change the `GridView` to `ListView` and `TargetType="GridViewItem"` to `TargetType="ListViewItem"`.

Comment: If I use the list view Item I can't customize the selection mode to be like the grid view

Comment: The selection mode should be the same in the `ListView`. Which mode are you talking about? Both controls inherit from the same base class.

Comment: I use the grid view because I not found the way to have a selection like a grd view : I wan't a border selection blue and I don't wan't to see a check box in every list item when I select multiple ones

Comment: You can easily customise the border color and turn off the checkbox function by setting `IsMultiSelectCheckBoxEnabled` to `False`.

Comment: Ok that's working but for the border I use : ListViewItemPresenter with theses options : without effect : SelectedBackground="White"
                                   BorderBrush="Blue" 
                                   BorderThickness="10"                                    
                                   SelectedBorderThickness="10"
                                    SelectedForeground="Red"

Comment: You can modify the style or more easily, use a `Grid` inside your `DataTemplate` so it can take up all the available space, and set its `BorderThickness` and `BorderBrush` to whatever you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147254/discussion-between-fandro-and-justin-xl).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want a single-column GridView. Try to use a ListView instead, and remove the custom ItemsPanelTemplate from your code. In the ListView items will use all the width available.

Alternatively set the HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" in your ItemsWrapGrid.

Comment: Setting the `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` won't stretch the content.